# JavaScript, having trouble changing an elements' style

Tags: javascript, html

So this is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <title>TEST</title>

        <style>
            body {
              background: #000000;
              color:#cccccc;
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0px;
              border: 0px;
            }
            canvas {
                      image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
                      -webkit-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
                      -ms-touch-action: none;
                      margin: 0px;
                      padding: 0px;
                      border: 0px;
            }
            :-webkit-full-screen #canvas {
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 100%;
            }
            div.gm4html5_div_class
            {
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0px;
              border: 0px;
            }

            div.gm4html5_login
            {
                 padding: 20px;
                 position: absolute;
                 border: solid 2px #000000;
                 background-color: #404040;
                 color:#00ff00;
                 border-radius: 15px;
                 box-shadow: #101010 20px 20px 40px;
            }
            div.gm4html5_cancel_button
            {
                 float: right;
            }
            div.gm4html5_login_button
            {
                 float: left;
            }
            div.gm4html5_login_header
            {
                 text-align: center;
            }

            :-webkit-full-screen {
               width: 100%;
               height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="gm4html5_div_class" id="gm4html5_div_id">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="480">
               <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas.</p>
            </canvas>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="html5game/TEST.js?GPJZB=444106034"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to change the style of `div.gm4html5_div_class` using js. I've tried a bunch of things, but no luck.

Can anyone please help me with this?
Also note that it might be because I don't know enough about js...

Comment: please include the js that you have tried/have currently that is attempting to change `div.gm4html5_div_class`

Comment: "I've tried a bunch of things..." Name one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document. querySelector` for this

```js
document.querySelector(".gm4html5_div_class").style.background = 'red'
```

```css
body {
 background: #ffffff;
 color:#cccccc;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}
canvas {
 image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
 -webkit-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
 -ms-touch-action: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}
:-webkit-full-screen #canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
div.gm4html5_div_class
{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
 background: green;
}

div.gm4html5_login
{
 padding: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 border: solid 2px #000000;
 background-color: #404040;
 color:#00ff00;
 border-radius: 15px;
 box-shadow: #101010 20px 20px 40px;
}
div.gm4html5_cancel_button
{
 float: right;
}
div.gm4html5_login_button
{
 float: left;
}
div.gm4html5_login_header
{
 text-align: center;
}

:-webkit-full-screen {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gm4html5_div_class" id="gm4html5_div_id">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="480">
  <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas.</p>
 </canvas>
</div>
```

Note: **Actual background colour of the div was `green`(in css), changed the background to `red` using javascript**

here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b355rhum/)**

Comment: This one worked great for me. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the class List using JavaScript.

```
var element = document.getElementById("YourDivsId");
element.classList.add("YourClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select the target DOM element by different ways.
for example using

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('gm4html5_div_class');
```

here the returned value is list of nodes with the given class. so to change the style of each individual element
you have to use a loop and change individual element style ,

```
for (var i=0; i<ele.length; i++) {
    ele[i].style.backgroundColor = "#e3e3e3";
}
```

another option

```
var ele = document.querySelector(".gm4html5_div_class");
```

the returned value is the firs occurrence of the c
lass, so here you can change the style easily for only one element returned.

if you want also to select all elements with the given class you can use

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".gm4html5_div_class");
```

and loop each element to change the style.